# ORA-01017 error when conecting to Oracle Database Standard Edition 2.12.2.0.1.0 for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, users

I've installed and created non-CDB database (single tenant) database. Created a user account using the SYS user, granted it the CONNECT and CREATE SESSION roles. When I attempt to login using the newly created account I get the "ORA-010170: invalid username/password; login denied" error.

I'm I missing something with respect to the Oracle 12c Standard database?? Since I've created a "normal" database I should be able to login with a non SYS account.

Thanks!!

Comment: ```ALTER USER account IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;```

Answer (score -1):

Check the netca config. There needs to be an entry in tnsnames.ora.